# Plotting a solution of a differential equation with Sagemath

Tags: plot, differential-equations, sage

I need to solve a differential equation. The solution will depend on t and q, and I need to define that q piecewise depending on t.

```
var('k,Tmax,Tmin,w,T0,q'); T=function('T')(t); Te=function('Te')(t);

assume(k>0); assume(Tmax>Tmin); Te(t)=(Tmax+Tmin)/2+(Tmax-Tmin)/2*sin(w*t);
```

Now this is the differential equation solution:

```
sol=desolve(diff(T(t),t)-q+k*(T(t)-Te(t)),[T,t],[0,T0]);
```

The solution with q=0 for example would be

```
sol.subs(Tmax=21.6,Tmin=15.2,k=0.024,q=0,T0=15.6,w=pi/12);
```

but I need that q to be a model for a heater that's off from 8 AM to 22 PM, and on from 22 PM to 8 AM. So I need to define a q function that if t mod 24 is between 8 and 22 its value is 0, and 0.054 otherwise.

I've been trying with the piecewise function but it's not plotting anything, I always get error messages.

Thanks for your time.